# Tensorflow viewing a uint8 tensor as a float32 tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a bunch of training example files in a custom format id like to load into a tensorflow model, but I can't figure out how to efficiently parse the data.

The files have a 20 byte header describing the number of features, number of labels, number of examples, etc. The header is followed by some number of examples. Each example is some number of float32s representing the features, followed by some number of uint8s representing the labels, so the rest of the file is an alternating pattern of floats and uints.

I have been using `tf.read_file` and `tf.decode_raw` to get the file as a vector of uint8s, and now id like to slice the features from the labels, and view the features vector as a float32 vector in little endian order. Any chance this sort of thing is possible in tensorflow?

I have been successfully parsing the files with `numpy` and converting the features and labels to `tf.constant`s, but it seems like it would be way more memory efficient to load it straight into tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's all fixed-size data, you need to de-interleave the data using [Slicing and Joining](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/array_ops) operators. Then, you can use `decode_raw` with `out_dtype=tf.float32` on the image data, and slice again to get your vectors individually.